# PHP display record from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to display the records stored in my database and here's my code on PHP:

```
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
$recipe_id = $_GET['recipe_id'];

$sql_check = "select * from user_favorites where user_id = '$user_id' and recipe_id = '$recipe_id'";
$query_check = mysql_query($sql_check);

$result_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_check)) {
$user_id = $row["user_id"];
$recipe_id = $row["recipe_id"];

$result_array[]= array("user_id"=> $user_id, "recipe_id"=> $recipe_id);
$json_encoded = json_encode($result_array);
echo "addToCallback(". $json_encoded.")";
}
?>
```

OUTPUT: addToCallback([{"user_id":"0","recipe_id":"0"}])

On my database table I already have a stored records, but why is it displaying only 0? I don't have "0" input on my table. Is there any problem with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is **VERY** vulnerable to SQL injections. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Please use `var_dump($row)` to inspect the row's content. That'd usually gives hints for debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 3 problems with your code:

1. You aren't formatting your query parts properly
2. You aren't check for possible errors
3. Most likely you're encoding wrong array

Item 2 is essential. You **always** need to be informed of **all** errors occurred - so you can take appropriate action and fix the problem.
Without error message you're blind and deaf.

So, here is an improved version.
It will either return encoded data or mysql error (in case you have display_errors turned on. otherwise error will be logged in web-servers error_log).
If there will be neither data nor error message - your query returned no rows then.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include("includes/connect.php");
$user_id   = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user_id']);
$recipe_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['recipe_id']);

$sql = "select * from user_favorites where user_id = '$user_id' and recipe_id = '$recipe_id'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()."[$sql]");

$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
$json_encoded = json_encode($result_array);
echo "addToCallback(". $json_encoded.")";
```

Comment: Hi! I' sorry, I'm a bit confuse here... I tried your code and it gives me an error: 

Notice: Query was empty[select * from user_favorites where user_id = '' and recipe_id = ''] ...
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given ...
addToCallback(null)

How come? I have data on the table.

Comment: No worries... I got it working with your code and some modifications I made with it. Thank you so much! *Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you are getting all the GET values
2. Change :

`$sql_check = "select * from user_favorites where user_id = '$user_id' and recipe_id = '$recipe_id'";`

to :

`$sql_check = "select * from user_favorites where user_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user_id)."' and recipe_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($recipe_id)."'";`

`echo $sql_check` and run in phpmyadmin and see the output

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your code and made an existing call

test.php?user_id=1&recipe_id=5

addToCallback([{"user_id":"1","recipe_id":"5"}])

non existing call returned me nothing :]